# Hide Msinfo32.exe when called from C# process execution?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a diagnostic program that outputs a copy of msinfo32.exe by using a "Process" object. Normally I hide these sort of diagnostics by settings the "CreateNoWindow" property to true.

The problem is, whenever I call it using a process.start() method, no matter what I do, the msinfo32.exe window shows up. Normally this doesn't occur with other command line programs like ipconfig. But msinfo seems to show up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you also try setting `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` ?

Comment: ipconfig doesn't have a GUI, so it's an entirely different kettle of fish.  If you really really need to hide the msinfo32 progress bar you could probably push it onto an alternate desktop - see CreateDesktop in the MSDN library.

Comment: If the UseShellExecute property is true, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored and a new window is created.

Comment: @EricLaw Those matter when you invoke some command line toll like ipconfig. Or in case of a GUI program you can suppress the extra command line window which may pop-up with command which invokes the GUI program. But you cannot hide the GUI program itself. Maybe you can move it offscreen or some other heck.

Comment: Some apps support the window positioning parameter of shellexecute (so you can run it minimized) but Msinfo32 doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51959808/10104464 I have encountered this problem, I solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility here : http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html 
  that you can use. 
The syntax for the command is like that :    hstart /NOCONSOLE "batch_file_1.bat"
and you can assign priorities also.
  Hope I helped you!