# How can i hide the msinfo32.exe process window?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im creating the file msinfo :

```
ProcessRun.Processing(contentDirectory, "msinfo32.exe" , "/nfo " + "\"" + contentDirectory + "\\msinfo.nfo" + "\"",false,"");
```

This is the class that create and usig the process to create the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen
{
    class ProcessRun
    {


        public void ProcessesRun()
        {

        }

        public static void Processing(string WorkingDirectory, string FileName, string Arguments, bool StandardOutput, string OutputFileName)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = StandardOutput;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
            proc.Start();
            if (StandardOutput == true)
            {
                string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                DumpOutput(WorkingDirectory + "\\" + OutputFileName, output);
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }

        private static void DumpOutput(string filename, string output)
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(filename);
            w.Write(output);
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Once the process start and running the msinfo32.exe there is a small window showing the process of the msinfo32.exe in the middle of the screen.

Its not the cmd window ! Its part of the msinfo32.exe 
Is there any way to hide this window while its Processing ?

[image]

Edited an image showing on the left my program and next to it on the right the small window of the msinfo32.exe that i want to hide.

Comment: What is the point of the empty public constructor of your class `ProcessRun`? If your class only contains those two (or however many) `static` methods, mark the class `static` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add:

```
 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native function `ShowWindow`. You will need to check out pinvoke to find how to use it otherwise I am happy to give you a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the window by referencing **user32.dll**.

Although the window will appear for a short time, it is possible to prevent the user from accidentally touching the cancel button.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen
{
    public class GetSystemInfo
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

        public void GetInfo(string path)
        {
            using (Process exeObj = new Process())
            {
                exeObj.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
                exeObj.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "/nfo ", path, @"\mysysinfo.nfo");

                exeObj.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                exeObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                exeObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                exeObj.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                exeObj.Start();
                exeObj.BeginOutputReadLine();
                exeObj.Close();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            const int SW_HIDE = 0;

            int hwnd = FindWindow(null, "System Information");

            if (hwnd != 0)
            {
                var num = ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```